# I am learning Redux thunk by using createAsynThunk. I try to delete an item in todoState but it doesn't work and i don't know the reason

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

My slices file filename: slices.ts

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction, configureStore, Middleware, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"; import { combineReducers } from "redux"; import { Todo } from "./Todo";

const myMiddleware: Middleware<{}, unknown> = ({ dispatch }) => next => action => { if (action.type === 'todo/addTodo' && action.payload.title.includes("fuck")) { action.payload.title = action.payload.title.replace("fuck", "love"); return dispatch(action); } return next(action); }

const wait = (ms: number): Promise => { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); }

export const deleteTodo = createAsyncThunk("todo/deleteTodo", async (id: number) => { await wait(1000); return id; })

const initialState: Todo[] = [] const todoSlice = createSlice({ name: 'todo', initialState, reducers: { addTodo: (state, action: PayloadAction) => { state.push(action.payload) }, }, extraReducers: (builder) => { builder.addCase(deleteTodo.fulfilled, (state, action) => { const newState = state.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload); return newState; } ) } })

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ todoReducer: todoSlice.reducer })

export const store = configureStore({ reducer: rootReducer, middleware: defaultMiddleware => defaultMiddleware().concat(myMiddleware) })
```

My action creators. filename: actioncreators.ts

```
import { createAction, createAsyncThunk, Dispatch } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"; import { Todo } from "./Todo";

export const addTodo = createAction('todo/addTodo', (todo: Todo) => { return { payload: todo } })
```

Todo interface, filename: Todo.ts

```
export interface Todo { id: number, title: string, completed: boolean }
```

I run my index file, filename: index.ts

```
import { store } from "./slices"; import { Todo } from "./Todo"; import { deleteTodo } from "./slices";

const todo1: Todo = { id: 1, title: "Do homework", completed: true }

const todo2: Todo = { id: 2, title: "Wake up", completed: true }

store.dispatch({ type: 'todo/addTodo', payload: todo1 }) store.dispatch({ type: 'todo/addTodo', payload: todo2 }) store.dispatch(deleteTodo(1)) console.log(store.getState().todoReducer)
```

I expect it would be

```
[ id: 2, title: 'Wake up', completed: true } ]
```

But actually it is.

```
[ id: 1, title: 'Do homework', completed: true }, id: 2, title: 'Wake up', completed: true } ]
```

Comment: Please, try to format your question better because it is unreadable as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. The reason you are getting the same result after delete is because you have wait in your `delete` handler. In the mean time, when wait is going on, your next statement executes (concept of call stack & task queue) which give the same result.

To validate this, add `wait` for the second `console.log` and you'll see the updated results.

Following is the link to the `stackblitz` template having your code:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-kcjjry?file=store.ts)

[image: console.log result]

Read more about JavaScript's Task queue & call stack
[call stack & event look](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/demystifying-asynchronous-javascript-event-loop-call-stack-task-queue-and-more-51fb748a4bd4)

Hope that answers your doubts.

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked when i add an asynchronous before i call dispatch!